# Choice of index on date range column having selectivity around 20 % and joined with other table

Tags: oracle, performance, query-performance

```
select  c.customer_name , c.customer_address, i.invoice_num, i.invoice_date,i.invoice_amount
from Customer c,   ---100 k rows
Invoice  i   ---- 10 M rows    
where c.cust_id=i.cust_id
AND c.customer_name=' Tarun Kumar'  -- exactly one row
AND i.invoice_date >= (sysdate-12)    -- 20 % of all rows
```

```
Customer Table
------------------
 customer_name,cust_id  --- Composite index

Invoice Table
----------------
 cust_id
```

Should I add the index on invoice_date ? Composite index (invoice_date, cust_id )

Comment: Try an index on `(cust_id, invoice_date)`

Comment: Should we add the index on invoice_date, as the selectivity is  20%?  Doesn't it to have a full table scan.  Why the order cust_id, invoice_date?

Comment: As per the least selectivity column comes first then on Invoice table composite Index (cust-id, invoice_date), but still not sure whether to include invoice_date in the index because it has selectivity more than 20%.

Comment: I suppose you already have an index on `invoice (cust_id)`, right? What is the performance of the query with that index? Then add the index on `invoice (cust_id, invoice_date)` and check performance again. Is the composite index used? Is performance better? (You can also drop the (cust_id) index as the composite can be used for queries that check only cust_id).

Answer (score 1):

`AND c.customer_name=' Tarun Kumar'  -- exactly one row`

So you should have an index on `customer(customer_name)`.

Knowing that the `customer_name` filter returns 1 row, the below is not so important:

```
Customer c,   ---100 k rows
Invoice  i   ---- 10 M rows  
i.invoice_date >= (sysdate-12)    -- 20 % of all rows
```

What matters is the result of these:

```
select count(*) from Customer c, Invoice i
where c.cust_id=i.cust_id and c.customer_name=' Tarun Kumar';

select count(*) from Customer c, Invoice i
where c.cust_id=i.cust_id and c.customer_name=' Tarun Kumar'
and i.invoice_date >= (sysdate-12);
```

The result can be between 0 and 2000000.

`Invoice.cust_id` is a foreign key column with a constraint referencing `Customer.cust_id`. If it is not, then it should be. Assuming OLTP.

Since `Invoice.cust_id` is a foreign key column, it is already indexed to speed up queries and avoid unnecessary locking issues. If it is not, then it should be. Assuming OLTP.

If the 2 above queries return similar results, then do not bother with the composite index, the index on `Invoice(cust_id)` is enough. If the 1st query returns a significantly higher (like orders of magnitudes) number than the 2nd, then sure, create an index on `Invoice(cust_id, invoice_date)`.

Comment: How does matter the count of rows of query 1 and query 2 to have index on invoice date ?